# Ruby-on-rails using cache in controllers to keep track of information for database updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

The table "Companies" has an associated table "Company Listings"  such that a Company has_many Company_Listings.  When  s Company is selected from the Companies Index page a page allowing insert/modify/delete of all Company_Listings for that Company is displayed.
(1) the Company is written to cache
(2) control passes to the Company_Listings pages
(3) where all the associated company_listings are displayed
(3) if update entered or enter new company_listing selected the Company_Listings Controller reads the Company cache and uses this to determine the Company id
(4)  I never get any errors in Development but I do get occasional errors on Heroku which appear to be caused by the loss of cached Company information.

Question
(1) is this the way to do it or should the company id be embedded in the route
(2) why do I only get this error i Heroku and not the development environment ?

Models

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  has_many :company_listings, dependent: :destroy

class CompanyListing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection 
  belongs_to :company
```

Controllers

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  ...
   def update
   Rails.cache.write("company", @company)
   ...

class CompanyListingsController < ApplicationController 
  def new_option
     @company = Rails.cache.read("company")
     @company_listing = CompanyListing.new
     @company_listing.company_id = @company.id
  end
```

Routes

```
resources :companies, only: [:destroy, :update]
resources :company_listings, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy] do
    collection do
      get 'edit_multiple'
      post 'update_multiple'
    end
 end
```

Questions
(1) is this the way to do it or should the company id be embedded in the route
(2) why do I only get this error i Heroku and not the development environment ?

routes
if editing company 
http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/company_listings/112/edit
where the company id = 112

should the routing be such that address is something like
http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/company/222/edit/company_listing/edit_multiple/ ?

any help/suggestions would be greatlyy appreciated - thanks - Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was causing the error in Heroku.  I had added a validation in the Company_Listing model.  This then casued the somewhat misleading Heroku error Heroku "missing company id".
So it wasn't the case that for some strange reason cache memory was beiing overwritten.  Thanks - Pierre